# Number of elements in Hom$(S_n,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: group-theory

Hox can I determine the number of elements in Hom$(S_n,\mathbb{C})$ for $ n\geq 1$?

I thought maybe I can use the thesis that for a normal subgroup $N\subset G$, and a subgroup $H\subset G$, there exists a natural isomorphism $H/(H\cap N)\underrightarrow{\sim}HN/N$, where Hom$(S_n,\mathbb{C})$ is one of the mentioned groups.

I also want to determine the number of elements in Hom$(S_n,\mathbb{C}^*)$ and Hom$(D_n,\mathbb{C})$, can I do that if I know how to do it for Hom$(S_n,\mathbb{C})$ or are the methods involved totally different?

Answer (score 2):

Any homomorphism from a finite group to $(\mathbb{C}, +)$ must be trivial. Suppose $f\in\text{Hom}(G, \mathbb{C})$, $G$ a finite group. For $a\in G$, the order of $a$ must be finite, so is the order of $f(a)$ in $\mathbb{C}$. But the only finite order element in $\mathbb{C}$ is 0.

For the second question: Let $f\in\text{Hom}(S_n, \mathbb{C}^*)$. Then $S_n/\text{ker}(f)$ is isomorphic to a finite subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^*$, which is abelian. It follows that $\text{ker}(f)$ must contain the commutator subgroup of $S_n$, which is the alternating group $A_n$. So $\text{ker}(f)$ can either be $A_n$ or the whole group $S_n$. So there are two elements in $\text{Hom}(S_n, \mathbb{C}^*)$, one of which is the trivial homomorphism, another being the homomorphism which sends even permutations to 1 and odd permutations to -1.

Comment: and Hom$(D_n,\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thanks. Though I know that (and use in my answer) the characteristic subgroup of $S_n$ is $A_n$, now I cannot recall the proof or locate where a proof can be found. Do you happen to know about that?

Comment: @charles_xavier Please see the first paragraph of my answer. I think that also answers your question.

Comment: Dear Alex, Lemma 4 of [this handout](http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~eal/S6.pdf) proves that the the commutator subgroup of $S_n$ is $A_n$, so that the abelianization $S_n^{ab}=S_n/[S_n,S_n]$ is the two-element group. This allows you to conclude since $\text{Hom}(S_n, \mathbb C^*)=\text{Hom}(S_n^{ab}, \mathbb C^*)$ [Recall that for an arbitrary group $G$ and an **abelian** group $A$ we have $\text{Hom}(G,A)=\text{Hom}(G^{ab},A)$]

Comment: Thank you, George! By `characteristic subgroup' in my answer I meant commutator subgroup. I used this wrong terminology to do a google search for the proof I wanted; no wonder nothing turned up.